# What is 1 damage point means in League of Legend?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is 1 damage point means - does it mean when auto attack, 1 damage will take 1 health from opponents?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it mean when auto attack, 1 damage will take 1 health from opponents?

On paper yes, that's it.
Now, they're is one major parameter to look after when you're ingame :

Opponent's armor. Armor reduces the physical damages you will take.
Physical damages come from :

- Auto Attacks (1 total AD = 1HP before armor reduction)
- Physical spells. You know the type of damages a spell deals by reading it.

Spells damages are based on ratios of either :

- Your Base AD. (what you see on your screenshot)
- Your Bonus AD. (comes from your runes/masteries/items)
- Your Total AD. (Base AD + Bonus AD)

[image: This is the official formula used in game]

To use Oak's exemple :
Let's say you're playing zed and you're lvl 6 :
You have 54.712 (+3.4 x6) = 78.712 Base AD.
You have 100 bonus AD from your runes+masteries+items = 178.712 Total AD.

Now let's say you hit your opponent with 1 auto attack + 1 E (which is level 1).
We will give this opponent 50 total armor and say you have 0 and 0% armor penetration.

Your auto will deal :
178.712 - ((100 / (100+178.712)) * 178.712) = 114.592 dmgs (that's the HPs your opponent will loose)

And your E will deal : 
65 + (100*0.8) = 145 dmgs.

you can also reduce your opponent armor with armor reduction items.
I hope this helped you, you can find every formula and every champ stats on the league of legend wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat badly phrased, because there are 4 types of Damage (*Physical, Magical, True and Pure*). There are also two stats that heavily influence damage (*Attack Damage and Ability Power*).

You seem to be referring to the latter: *Attack Damage*. Attack Damage, or AD for short, is a value that determines the strenght of your basic attacks (all Champions have AD). 1 AD = 1 Physical Damage (Before armor).

Furthermore some Champions also have abilities that scale with AD. What this means is that some Champions get more damage on some abilities, depending on how much AD you have. For example, Zed's Shadow Slash:

> Zed and his shadows slash, dealing 65/90/115/140/165 (+80% bonus Attack Damage)

This means that at max level Zed's E (Shadow Slash), assuming you have 100 Attack Damage will do:

165 + AD*0.8 <=> 165 + 80 = 245 Physical Damage

---

In other words, and to be more specific towards your description, 1 AD = 1 damage the target will take from basic attacks, but it also increases some ability's damage. All of this is before armour reduces the damage taken.

Comment: I've never heard of pure dmgs, what are they ? And your calcul is false since it's it's 80% of bonus AD and not total AD.

Comment: It was an example of how it influences damage. The 100 AD I mentioned is implied to be bonus AD. Regarding Pure damage, it's exactly the same as True damage, except it pierces innvulnerability and immortality (meaning Tryndamere will DIE to this damage, and Guardian's Angel won't revive). It's exclusive to the beam ray in the nexus

Comment: Ok, I didn't it was called this way. Thanks for teaching me smth new about the league ! :D

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, but in reality the amount of health that the opponent will lose will also depend on their armor.

Also your attack damage (generally referred to as AD) will affect some skills and items causing them to do more damage.

Also note that there is base damage, which is what your champion would have normally at a given level and then items add bonus damage on top of it. This difference has some impact on certain aspects of the game, such as some skills only scaling off bonus or base.